# R script output values into another folder or directory

Tags: r, output

After running my R script in the terminal I get two output data files: a.dat and b.dat. My goal is to directly divert these output files into a new folder.
Is there any way to do something like this:

```
 Rscript myscript.R > folder
```

Note: For writing the output file I simply use this:

```
 write(t(result1), file = "a.dat", ncolumns = 5, append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you post a little more information?  What command are you using in the script to write the files?  Presumably it has an file name argument.  If so you could specify output folder there.  An alternative would be to save your location then `setwd()` output your file and go back to starting point- but this is less clean.

Comment: You can use the *sink* function, see the example in the follow link: https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/library/base/html/sink.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by doing the following:

1. I created an output folder 'output'
2. I added the full path of the output in myscript.R as

> `write(t(result1), file = "home/Documents/output/a.dat", ncolumns = 5, append=TRUE)`

Solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use write.table create two csv files like this:

**A minimal working example:**

using a r-script called "Rfile.r" in the directory "adir" in my "Dokumente" folder. the script reads the first two inputs , a numeric as the input argument for the function , aswell as a character string with the output-target-directory . (you could also do filenames , etc of course..)

> Rfile.r ::

```
# set arguments, to later specifiy in terminal , 
# one numeric and one target directory
arg <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

n<-as.numeric(arg[1])
path<-as.character(arg[2])

## A random function two create two csv 's 
fun <- function(n) {  
  data.a <-data.frame(rep("Some Data", n))
  data.b<-data.frame(rnorm(1:n))
  data<-list(data.a,data.b)
  return(data)
  }

# create data using input arg[1], aka 'n'
data<-fun(n)

# now the important Part: using write.table with the arg[2] aka 'path' 
# :
write.table(data[1],file =paste(path,"/data_a.csv", sep = ""))
write.table(data[2],file =paste(path,"/data_b.csv", sep = ""))

## write terminal output message using cat()
cat(paste("Your input was :" ,arg[1],sep="\t"),
    paste( "your target path was:" ,arg[2] ,sep="\t"), sep = "\n")
```

then run in a terminal :

```
$ Rscript ~/Dokumente/adir/Rfile.r 3 ~/Dokumente/bdir
```

it creates two csv's in the directory **"bdir"** called **"data_a.csv"** and **"data_b.csv"**  where **3** was the numeric input for the function in **Rfile.r**

Comment: The  "/data_a.csv" gave me a good idea. If I add the path something like  "/Documents/output/a.dat" works fine as long as the output folder already exists.

Comment: You could also let R create a new directory with the dir.create () function